# NewsAPI endpoints behave differently with percent-encoded query

Tags: json, api, get, urlencode

I'm trying to use [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/) service that return news articles as a response to a request. It has 2 endpoints, "Everything" and "Top headlines" and according to the docs, both support keyword searching using parameter "q".

Whenever I search with percent-encoded keyword, I get responses from "Everything" but when I use the same keyword for "Top headlines" I always get 0 articles as a response. This issue doesn't happen with English keywords.

I emailed NewsAPI support but I got no response in 2 weeks, and I'm wondering if I missed something in the docs, or if my issue can be reproduced by someone else.

**Parameters**

API key(apiKey): Shown in the link below as [] is required for all requests. It is filled with my key that works with everything else. I have [free developer account](https://newsapi.org/pricing) but I couldn't find any restrictions mentioned that might have affected this issue.

Keyword(q): "政府" meaning "government" in Japanese which should eliminate possibility of a keyword lacking latest news due to popularity. I have the same issue with any other percentage-encoded Japanese keyword I tried.

**My requests**

1. https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?apiKey=[]&q=%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C
2. https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?apiKey=[]&q=%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C

**Raw Response**

1. {"status":"ok","totalResults":21795,"articles":[.....
2. {"status":"ok","totalResults":0,"articles":[]}

Comment: Are you sure that news from "Everything" does exist in "Top headlines"?

Comment: @Aakash Martand From trying English keywords I'm certain that what you said is conditional. For some really popular keywords(ex. U.S.) there's so many articles that, news that appear on "Top headlines" often don't with "Everything" and vice versa. The issue is that with entirely percent-encoded keyword, "Top headlines" endpoint always seem to return 0 results no matter what it is.